# Android XML parsing with XmlPullParse

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I am new to XML to parsing and dont know how to go about getting certain details from an xml file. In the following code, (Android Java) I get the location from the  tag. Very straight forward;

```
public void readXML(String xmlToRead) throws XmlPullParserException {

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xmlToRead)); 

        WeatherDetails weatherDetails = new WeatherDetails();

        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();                        

          while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                      weatherDetails.setWeatherLocation(xpp.nextText());
                      weather_userlocation.setText(weatherDetails.getWeatherLocation());

                  }
              }
              xpp.next();
          }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is an example XML I'm attempting to parse: 
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.28331&lon=-84.1435136&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml

Near the bottom of the XML, there is a segment:

```
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
<temperature type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1">
<value>33</value>
</temperature>
```

The value I want is inside the value tag, but there are numerous value tags throughout the XML. How can I point and retrieve this specific one?

Thank you all!

Heres my implementation of your suggestion:

```
while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                  String name = xpp.getName();

                  if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                      weatherDetails.setWeatherLocation(xpp.nextText());
                      weather_userlocation.setText(weatherDetails.getWeatherLocation());
                  }
                  if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")) {
                      weather_apparenttemp.setText("Found TEMPERATURE tag!");

                      xpp.next();
                      if(xpp.getName().equals("value")) {
                          weather_apparenttemp.setText(xpp.nextText());
                      }

                  }

              }
              xpp.next();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is search until you find the temperature tag using something like

```
        String name = xpp.getName();
            if(name.equals("temperature"))
            {
                if(xpp.next().equals("value")
                { String temp = xpp.next.getValue()}
            }
```

Not 100%sure on the synax, its been a while since I used this but that should be the general idea.

Another alternative is to call another function that takes the parser as a parameter and then you can search within that, but thats more for if you have odd structure to the xml.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I understand it, and it seems like it would be that perfect answer but everytime I run it, the application crashes...heres the code I run:

Comment: Sorry new to the site I will add the code mod to the original post:

Comment: what is the error you're getting? it should come out in the logcat, if you could add that to the question I might be able to help, also please make sure its a copy paste from the logcat output